# Get selected element by combobox from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, combobox

I have an combobox that filled with xml data. The valu member is  from xml file. I would like read the selected element from xml file.

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"data\tools.xml");
    var ToolData = from r in xmlDocument.Descendants("ToolClass").Where
                   (r => (string)r.Attribute("ToolID") == ToolListComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
                   select new
                   {
                       Tooldia = r.Element("ToolDia").Value,
                       Tooltooth = r.Element("ToolTooth").Value,
                       Toolfeed= r.Element("ToolFeedPerTooth").Value,
                       Toolcut = r.Element("ToolCuttingSpeed").Value                               
                   };
    foreach(var r in ToolData)
    {
        CalcToolDia.Text = r.Tooldia.ToString();
    }
```

I tried with this code, but not work.

EDIT:
I have this XMl file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfToolClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ToolClass>
    <ToolID>1</ToolID>
    <ToolName>Multiflute Endmill</ToolName>
    <ToolDia>8</ToolDia>
    <ToolTooth>4</ToolTooth>
    <ToolApmxs>32</ToolApmxs>
    <ToolCuttingSpeed>150</ToolCuttingSpeed>
    <ToolFeedPerTooth>0.04</ToolFeedPerTooth>
    <ToolAe>8</ToolAe>
    <ToolAp>4</ToolAp>
    <ToolManufacturer>SECO</ToolManufacturer>
    <ToolSerial>DKFLJDSKJ</ToolSerial>
  </ToolClass>
  <ToolClass>
    <ToolID>2</ToolID>
    <ToolName>Multiflute Endmill</ToolName>
    <ToolDia>4</ToolDia>
    <ToolTooth>4</ToolTooth>
    <ToolApmxs>25</ToolApmxs>
    <ToolCuttingSpeed>235</ToolCuttingSpeed>
    <ToolFeedPerTooth>0.03</ToolFeedPerTooth>
    <ToolAe>4</ToolAe>
    <ToolAp>0.4</ToolAp>
    <ToolManufacturer>SECO</ToolManufacturer>
    <ToolSerial>DJFKLSL</ToolSerial>
  </ToolClass>
</ArrayOfToolClass>
```

The combobox contain this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"data\tools.xml");
            var toolist = xmlDocument.Descendants("ToolClass")
                                                  .Select(tc => new
            {
            Display = tc.Element("ToolDia").Value + "x" + tc.Element("ToolApmxs").Value + " mm - " + tc.Element("ToolName").Value,
            Value = tc.Element("ToolID").Value
             }).ToList();

            ToolListComboBox.DisplayMember = "Display";
            ToolListComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
            ToolListComboBox.DataSource = toolist;
```

When I select an item in combobox then she give me the ToolID. 
After this I would like to read the elemnts from xml file where ToolID is the combobox selected ToolID.

Comment: You should be comparing `ToolListComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()` to `r.Attribute("ToolID").Value`. Your `foreach` makes no sense. I don't understand what issue you're actually encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mistake is - where you are using attribute instead of element. Change it to

```
(string)r.Element("ToolID").Value
```

This is how it will look

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"data\tools.xml");
    var ToolData = from r in xmlDocument.Descendants("ToolClass").Where
                   (r => (string)r.Element("ToolID").Value == ToolListComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
                   select new
                   {
                       Tooldia = r.Element("ToolDia").Value,
                       Tooltooth = r.Element("ToolTooth").Value,
                       Toolfeed= r.Element("ToolFeedPerTooth").Value,
                       Toolcut = r.Element("ToolCuttingSpeed").Value                               
                   };
    foreach(var r in ToolData)
    {
        CalcToolDia.Text = r.Tooldia.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, there is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understand correctly you have an elements value and you want to retrieve the entire element providing this value - maybe try below.

```
To modify my sample provided to align to your example:

XElement root = XElement.Load(@"data\tools.xml");  
IEnumerable<XElement> address =  
    from el in root.Elements("ToolClass")  
    where (string)el.Attribute("ToolID") ==ToolListComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()  
    select el;  
foreach (XElement el in address)  
    Console.WriteLine(el.Tooldia.ToString());
```

Comment: Source for above it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-attribute